# Comparison of Repository definitions

Tags: c#

I've seen a repository pattern been defined in two ways. The fist method (below) is the more common way, however, definitely the best programmer I met uses method two. I was wondering if there are particular advantages of defining a repository one way over the other:

Method 1

```
readonly IRepository _repository;
```

Method 2

```
 IRepository Repository { get; }
```

Comment: it totally depends what's required if repository needs to be exposted then make property otherwise field should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's private, then go with the first way. By the way the underscores in private members is a bad naming convention nowadays

```
readonly IRepository repository;
```

The second way is better when you want to share your repository outside the class that declares it.

It can also be used for property injection 
,>You should use property injection (or setter injection) when object creation of your type is out of your control